# django model.save() alternative without changing id

Tags: django, django-models

I noted that invoking 'save()' on an existing django object , the original id of the object will be changed when I just want to update some value of its attribute. So is there any method, e.g. update(?), on the object that allows me to do that, i.e. changing attribute values while remaining the same id?

Comment: Id doesn't change when you save an object. Please show your code if you need help with it.